# How to get feed from group using Facebook Graph SDK JS

Tags: javascript, facebook, graph

I get this error

**To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review."**

I have api call by JS

```
FB.api(
            '/magisterhydraulics/feed',
            'GET',
                {},
            function(response) {
                // Insert your code here
                getGroupPostsCallback(response);

            }
        );
function getGroupPostsCallback(r) {
    console.log(r);
}
```

This looks like i should submit review in app dashboard, but i simply need to get posts from group.
I used this api tool and it works fine
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwMGb.png)

Comment: That’s not a group, but a page. If this isn’t your page, then you will need to submit PPCA for review. If you have admin access, then you can use your page access token - but then this needs to be done on the server-side, because you must not expose that kind of token in client-side code to begin with.

Comment: I got application access token. I don't want users to click login button. But in Details for Page Public Content Access i have to fill instructions how user logging in and getting posts. How can i do it if i use application access token where no user can see and interact with facebook at all

Comment: You don’t want PPCA - that is for when you need to get data from other pages, that you don’t have admin access to. _“I don't want users to click login button”_ - that’s why I said you should use your page access token  and do it on the server side. _“I got application access token”_ - your app access token must not be exposed in client-side code either, that would be even worse than exposing a page token. If you want to do this client-side, then having users login so that you can use their user access token, would be the only option. (Plus, in that case you would need to submit for PPCA.)